# PyCharm not running project via built-in run, but run in terminal

Tags: python, django, pycharm

PyCharm perfectly runs the project, when starting from its Terminal, via command: `py manage.py runserver 8000`

But when I try to launch the same project via green button (Run), then I get this error:

```
E:\work\wowzers-webapp\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/work/wowzers-webapp/manage.py runserver 8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/work/wowzers-webapp/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:/work/wowzers-webapp/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\work\wowzers-webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\work\wowzers-webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 334, in execute
    parser = CommandParser(usage='%(prog)s subcommand [options] [args]', add_help=False, allow_abbrev=False)
  File "E:\work\wowzers-webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 48, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_abbrev'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This error started to appear after I updated project's django version from 2.2.7 to 3.0.2

I've checked Run configuration and it is the same `python manage.py runserver 8000`
I even copy-paste the same run command, that pycharm uses to launch project, into terminal: `E:/work/wowzers-webapp/manage.py runserver` and in terminal project starts normally.
Both in terminal and in Run configuration the virtualenv python is being used, so they are the same.

Could you please say, should I check? 
I already tried:

1. Invalidate cache and restart
2. Delete venv folder and install everything again
3. Googling ~2 hours for this error didn't give me any help, so I decided to ask here, as I go in loops..

Additional info: my current Python version 3.7.2, but it shouldn't say anything much, because in terminal it is launching normally..

Comment: I would guess you have either got 2 different venvs, or one of the runs you are doing isn't using the venv.

Comment: "This error started to appear after I updated project's django version from 2.2.7 to 3.0.2" - how did you do this upgrade?

Comment: @TomDalton By changing Django version of virtual environment from 2.2.7 to 3.0.2.
And going through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/upgrade-version/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/ and making sure that it will work.
Anyway, the project launches normally through terminal and I suppose that there is some PyCharm config, which fail to start. I'm just curious if somebody knows.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was because of Google App Engine SDK. There is a class in Django, where this error happened:

```
class CommandParser(ArgumentParser):
    """
    Customized ArgumentParser class to improve some error messages and prevent
    SystemExit in several occasions, as SystemExit is unacceptable when a
    command is called programmatically.
    """
    def __init__(self, *, missing_args_message=None, called_from_command_line=None, **kwargs):
        self.missing_args_message = missing_args_message
        self.called_from_command_line = called_from_command_line
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

On this line: `super().__init__(**kwargs)` 
So, as I understoon, because of GAE SDK that class, `CommandParser`, was inheriting `ArgumentParser`not from Django, but from GAE SDK. And GAE's `ArgumentParser`class doesn't support `'allow_abbrev'` parameter.
But after I deleted GAE SDK, it started to run fine. And then I reinstalled GAE SDK, it runs normally again now.